# Inputs generated by Javascript are being ignored

Tags: javascript, php, forms, dom, error-handling

Basically, it's a form that needs specific information, **"Tamanho"/"Tamanhos" means "size"/"sizes"**, which I have a list of acceptable sizes that goes from 8 to 30 that are registered in a database (to make it easier to add more  acceptable sizes if needed), the user should be able to chose many "sizes" and put a quantity of "how many products of that size?" in an input right after it.

I was able to create an JavaScript function `AddTam()` called by a button that generates one more block to fill, with a select, and all the block's select inputs are named Tam[], so their values pass as an array, and their respective inputs named as "TamQnt8", the number 8 at the end refers to the size chosen, it changes every time the user chooses other size for the same block using other function `DefTam()`, that way, I could verify the sizes array in the Back-End, and use it to get their respective quantities and organize it all in an array, to finally send it to the database.

But for some reason, when I test if the information is passing through correctly, it doesn't send any data in the key "Tam" saying it's undefined when I tested it, in PHP I'm testing: `if(!empty($_POST['Tam']))` but i also tried `isset()`.

I just don't know what's wrong, so I was asking if isn't it the method I'm using `insertAdjacentHTML()` to generate the blocks, and if it works as well as `createElement()` in forms.

Also, when I created the blocks manually and instead of many selects I used checkboxes, it was working, just decided to change to the generated method because the checkboxes took way too much space in the screen, even worse for mobile.

Here's a simplification of the code in HTML:

```
<form method="post">
    <section>
            <div class="littlebutton" id="addTamanho" onclick="AddTam()">Add Tamanho</div>
    </section>

    <script>
        var contador = 0;

        function AddTam(){
            let tamTitulo = document.querySelector('#addTamanho');

            tamTitulo.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend",
            '<div class="cellTam cell">'+
            '<select name="Tam[]" class="'+contador+'tam8 '+contador+'" onchange="DefTam(this)">'+
            '<?php foreach ($_SESSION["tamanhos"] as $key => $value) { ?>'+
            '<option value="<?php echo $value["tamanho"];?>"><?php echo $value["tamanho"];?></option>'+
            '<?php }?>'+
            '</select>'+
            'Tem => <input class="qnt" id="'+contador+'tam8" name="TamQnt8" type="number" min=1>'+
            '</div>');
            contador++
        }

        function DefTam(ElementTam){
            let infoTam = ElementTam.value;
            let refTam = ElementTam.getAttribute("class");
            refTam = refTam.split(" ");
            let relInput = document.getElementById(refTam[0]);

            ElementTam.setAttribute("class", refTam[refTam.length-1]+"tam"+infoTam+" "+refTam[refTam.length-1]);
            relInput.setAttribute("name", "TamQnt"+infoTam);
            relInput.setAttribute("id", refTam[refTam.length-1]+"tam"+infoTam);
        }
    </script>

    <button class="post" name="Inserir" type="submit">Postar</button>
</form>
```

Output: [The Add Tamanho button, 3 generated blocks of the form and the Elements tab of browser's Developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MChB.png)

Sorry if I wrote something wrong or weirdly, still learning English, or if it's just a silly mistake in my code, also, any help is welcome.

Comment: I don-t think you should use multiple elements with same name Tam[]. Try just one with name Tam

Comment: @Spikolynn I've tried generating only one now and put its name as only "Tam", didn't work, and at least with checkboxes the "Tam[ ]" in all of them works great to get all values in an array. And as I searched, I think you can do it with... any input? I don't know for sure. But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Maybe try inspecting the posted data in the Network tab of browser's Developer tools?

Comment: @Spikolynn I put an image of that in the post as "Output", it looks right to me, it generates the "blocks" correctly and all selects are named "Tam[ ]", it's like those inputs just don't actually exist in the document, but they are being generated inside the form tag, so...I don't know, But thanks again for the suggestion.

Comment: @Jônatan I don't see the contents of the "Network" tab in the image. You should click on that tab, then create the request (click button), then inspect the posted data as it was sent.

Comment: @Spikolynn Oh sorry, I got confused since I didn't used that tab yet, the "Tam[]" doesn't seem to exist, it should be right after "Cor", as [you can see there](https://imgur.com/a/Tv5bYXD). Why?

Comment: @Spikolynn Also thank you, it's a really useful tool, that I didn't know it could be used that way.

Comment: Probably connected to three tam[] selects. Try just one select with a normal name

Comment: @Spikolynn I've tried making one select in the HTML named "teste", it worked, then I copied and pasted the same select two more times and changed the name to "teste[]", it also worked, it was posted as a array, but if I press the button to generate only one select with javascript, or many, for some reason it's ignored.

Comment: Also I just tried to copy and paste 2 times the strings inside the javascript (insertAdjacentHTML), where they appear, and it also worked.

It just doesn't work when it's generated by javascript.

Comment: I've made a little test with "createElement()", an input named "test", it was also ignored.... I don't know why, but I think I should change my question since none of them worked.